# Netbeans 7.3 + Apache Tomcat 7.0.39: HttpMonitor won't start

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I just added Tomcat 7.0.39 to my (windows) system.  Created a catalina_base directory and populated it with files.  Then configured the server in netbeans pointing it to the correct catalina_home and catalina_base directories.  Netbeans can start the server fine, but it cannot enable HttpMonitor.  Checking "Enable Http Monitor" results in the following error when I try to start tomcat.

Tomcat 7.0.27 works fine, config looks the same, permissions look the same.

```
NetBeans: Deploying on Apache Tomcat 7.0.39
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Operation failed, error occurred when setting up the HTTP Monitor support. The HTTP Monitor has been disabled,  you can try to restart the operation now. If you would like to enable the HTTP Monitor again, make sure you have write permissions to <CATALINA_BASE>/conf/web.xml file and <CATALINA_HOME>/lib directory and check the "Enable HTTP Monitor" checkbox in the Tomcat properties.
Deployment error: Operation failed, error occurred when setting up the HTTP Monitor support. The HTTP Monitor has been disabled,  you can try to restart the operation now. If you would like to enable the HTTP Monitor again, make sure you have write permissions to <CATALINA_BASE>/conf/web.xml file and <CATALINA_HOME>/lib directory and check the "Enable HTTP Monitor" checkbox in the Tomcat properties.
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:230)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:130)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:212)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Netbeans wants to write to < CATALINA_HOME >/lib in order to store org-netbeans-modules-schema2beans.jar and org-netbeans-modules-web-httpmonitor.jar.

I think this is a netbeans bug.  It should store the jars in < CATALINA_BASE >/nblib.